# Некорректное отображение цветов в дочернем элементе ExpendableListView android

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток . Уже второй день пытаюсь разобраться с этим вопросом . Должен быть список с выделением другим цветом лучшего предложения иным от default.

Должно быть так 
[image: должно быть]

Но в результате все мешается 
[image: ![но так]

В чем может быть проблема ?
Код адаптера:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    DetailInfo detailInfo = (DetailInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
    }

    TextView bankName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bankName);
    bankName.setText(detailInfo.getName().trim());

    TextView dateOfUpdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DateofUpdate);
    dateOfUpdate.setText(detailInfo.getDate().trim());

    TextView currencySell = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CurrencySell);
    currencySell.setTag(childPosition);
    currencySell.setText(detailInfo.getSell().trim());

    TextView currencyBuy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CurrencyBuy);
    currencyBuy.setTag(childPosition);
    currencyBuy.setText(detailInfo.getBuy().trim());

    if(detailInfo.isBestBuyDeal())
    {
        currencyBuy.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,150,0));
    }
    if(detailInfo.isBestSellDeal())
    {
        currencySell.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,150,0));
    }

    return view;
}
```

DetailInfo:

```
public class DetailInfo implements Comparable<DetailInfo>{

private String name = "";
private String date ="";
private String buy = "";
private String sell = "";
private Map.Entry<Boolean,Boolean> bestDeal = null;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDate() { return date; }

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getBuy() {
    return buy;
}

public void setBuy(String buy) {
    this.buy = buy;
}

public String getSell() {
    return sell;
}

public void setSell(String sell) {
    this.sell = sell;
}

public Map.Entry<Boolean,Boolean> getBestDeal() { return bestDeal; }

public void setBestDeal(Map.Entry<Boolean,Boolean> bestDeal)  {
    this.bestDeal = bestDeal;
}

public Boolean isBestBuyDeal() { return bestDeal.getKey(); }

public Boolean isBestSellDeal() { return bestDeal.getValue(); }

@Override
public int compareTo(DetailInfo another) {
    return this.getName().compareTo(another.getName());
}
```

}

child_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bankName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/DateofUpdate"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:text="Покупка:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BuyAmount"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CurrencyBuy"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/BuyAmount"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/BuyAmount"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BuyAmount"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Продажа:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Sell"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CurrencyBuy"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CurrencyBuy"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CurrencyBuy"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CurrencySell"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CurrencyBuy"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Sell"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Sell"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Для какого элемента в адаптере цвет не поменялся, какой должен быть цвет и как выглядит метод проверки?

Comment: Для TextView id = BuyAmount & SellAmount в child_row и id = currencyBuy & currencySell в адаптере. Там же и првоерка.

Comment: Вам надо прописать else для своих проверок, в которых устанавливать deafult цвет. Ваши view переиспользуются, а цвет остается от предыдущего item'а.

Comment: если пушу else , то всё меняет в default

Comment: "если пушу else , то всё меняет в default" - покажите код

Comment: Упс , всё помого , спасибо .Все это вред копипаста )

Answer (score 0):

Вью внуть разных списков как правило используются повторно. Если вы что-то меняете только при каком-то условии, то нужно при невыполнении этого условия менять это обратно:

```
if (detailInfo.isBestSellDeal()) {
    currencySell.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,150,0));
} else {
    currencySell.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
}
```

PS цвета, отступы, текст и вообще все что можно вынести в ресурсы, лучше выносить в ресурсы.